# When the EM vector field is given a mass by Higgs mechanism, why isn't this equivalent to a massive photon?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, vacuum, higgs, symmetry-breaking

In chapter 6 of Classical Theory of Gauge Fields (Rubakov), we are presented with a scalar field $\phi$ coupled to the electromagnetic vector potential $A_\mu$. In this Lagrangian there is a quartic term which provides us with spontaneous symmetry breaking. After working through some transformations and recasting this in terms of a perturbation $\chi$ away from the equilibrium field value we are left with the following Lagrangian:

$$ \mathcal{L}=-\dfrac{1}{4} B^2_{\mu\nu} + \dfrac{e^2\phi_0^2}{2}B_{\mu}B_{\mu} + \dfrac{1}{2}\left(\partial_{\mu}\chi\right)^2-\mu^2 \chi^2 $$

where $B_\mu$ and $B_{\mu\nu}$ are the vector potential and field strength tensor respectively, after an appropriate gauge transformation.

This is where we see the Higgs mechanism, our $\chi$ field still has mass as we expect. Our massless vector field $B_\mu$ is now given a mass. On the following page (p108) we are told that the Nambu-Goldstone field $\theta$ (the part of $\phi$ which is orthogonal to $\chi$, and is massless by Goldstone's theorem) has been 'eaten'by the vector field and has given $B$ a mass.

Given that the $B$ potential has a mass, and that this potential describes the electric and magnetic fields, surely this implies that photons (excitations in EM fields and thus in $B$ potential) have a mass given by $e\phi_0$?

Comment: Surely; see [this](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Englert-Brout-Higgs-Guralnik-Hagen-Kibble_mechanism#Goldstone.27s_U.281.29_model).  So this is not the vacuum, but a model of a superconductor. What, exactly, is the question?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I'm not sure I understand? All we are doing is coupling a massive charged particle to the vector potential - I dont see how this has anything to do with a superconductor? We have a massive vector field and photons are EM excitations so surely they have this same mass?

Comment: Additionally I'm unsure what your link means when discussing the volume or Fock space or the superposition of states - I am approaching this purely from a classical field theory point of view.

Comment: Photons are resoundingly quantum, but, even classically, magnetic flux exclusion from a superconductor in the [Meissner effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissner_effect#Paradigm_for_the_Higgs_mechanism)   corresponds to the Higgs-induced mass generation for the Abelian gauge field.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Ah okay, I think I'm starting to understand - so because we are using the KG equation, our scalar field has to represent particles with spin-0. This obviously doesn't correspond to electrons however it can correspond with a Cooper pair and thus this massive vector field describes EM in a superconductor. Outside of this, there aren't any pairs so this coupling doesn't have an effect. A similar discussion of symmetry breaking etc but with the Dirac equation would presumably give a description of EM interacting with electrons but with a massless EM field?

Comment: Very schematically, the scalar field represents phenomenological parameters associated to Cooper pairs, introduced by Landau and Ginsburg before their invention.  The electrons in the superconductor interact normally with the field. It is a long story... Rest assured that this Abelian Higgs mechanism you are studying is an unphysical  warmup exercise for the non-Abelian version, of importance in the EW interactions of particle physics.